# Building CPU usage graph in Grafana for Docker container

Tags: docker, cpu, grafana, prometheus, cadvisor

I have connected cAdvisor -> Prometheus and Grafana to get graphs for my Docker containers. One of them is the CPU load, but i can only see the cumulative usage lines and not actually a value at the moment. Id love to see somethin similar cAdvisor is showing. Whts the way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `irate()` and `rate()` functions. Using `irate(my_metric[5m])` will calculate the per-second value for you.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be close to what ive been looking for,